# Which postgis extension to choose?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Running ubuntu-20.04 I installed postgresql-13, postgis-3 and pgAdmin4 through apt. After creating a database I want to create a postgis extension. PgAdmin4 lets me choose between `postgis` and `postgis-3`.
What is the difference and which should I choose?

Comment: What PostgreSQL version are you using? When are on 12 (or later), PostGIS 3 makes more sense: A.4. Release 3.0.0

Release date: 2019/10/20

This version requires PostgreSQL 9.5+-12 and GEOS >= 3.6+ Additional features and enhancements enabled if you are running Proj6+, PostgreSQL 12, and GEOS 3.8.0

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your answer. I installed postgresql-13 and postgis-3. Why does pgAdmin show me both of these options, when I only specifically installed postgis-3?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pgAdmin, can't help you there.

Comment: You see both, because you installed the software for both.

Comment: when running `dpkg -l | grep postgis` this is what i get:

1. ```ii  postgis  3.1.0+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1
```
2. ```ii  postgis-doc  3.1.0+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1
```
3. ```ii  postgresql-13-postgis-3  3.1.0+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1
```
4. ```ii  postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts  3.1.0+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1
```

can you explain or point me to some explanation for the difference between the first and third? Thank you